# EditText/Checkbox inside ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview, android-edittext

I am writting code to insert `EditText` and `checkbox` inside the `ListView` and In this `CheckBox` will be only for first 7 rows and then `EditText` will come in each row.
The below code works fine for the first time view. but when I scroll down the View...`Checkbox` comes instead of the `EditView` . means `EditText` gets hides and `CheckBox` comes for which i have written the visibility code below . PLease can you help where I am going wrong.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {



    View vi=convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;

    if(convertView==null){ 

        /********** Inflate tabitem.xml file for each row ( Defined below ) ************/
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tabitem, null); 

        /******** View Holder Object to contain tabitem.xml file elements ************/
        holder=new ViewHolder();
        holder.text=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        holder.check =(CheckBox)vi.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
         holder.text2=(EditText)vi.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
          holder.text2.setTag(1);
       int position12 = (Integer)holder.text2.getTag();
       System.out.print(position12 + "value");

       /************  Set holder with LayoutInflater ************/
        vi.setTag(holder);


        j++;

        if(j<8){
       holder.text2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
       holder.check.setX(-150);
        }else
        {
             holder.check.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }



    }
    else  
        holder=(ViewHolder)vi.getTag();

    holder.text2.getText();
       if(data.size()<=0)
    {
        holder.text.setText("No Data");

        holder.text2.getText();
 //        Log.v("BBBB",  holder.text2.getText().toString());

    }
    else
    {
        /***** Get each Model object from Arraylist ********/
        tempValues=null;
        tempValues = (ListModel) data.get(position);

        /************  Set Model values in Holder elements ***********/
         holder.text.setText(tempValues.getCompanyName());

         holder.text2.getText();
                         /******** Set Item Click Listner for LayoutInflater for each row ***********/
         vi.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(position));
    }

    Log.v("DDD",  holder.text2.getText().toString());
    return vi;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the `ListView` behavior , as it `recycles` the views. The problem is `ListView` is reusing the first visible item views for the other child items.

You can fix this by informing the `ListView` that you have two different type of view. If you look at the `BaseAdapter` `getViewTypeCount()` method returns count as 1.

so you need to override the `getViewTypeCount()` in your custom adapter and return that you have two different views.

```
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2;
}
```

And , `getItemViewType()` by default returns 0. But your item `< 8` is different from other, so tell the `ListView` that your item at position <8 is different type, like this

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if(position <8)
            return 0;
        else
            return 1;
}
```

EDIT:

If you need to input in `EditText` in `ListView` set android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"  in manifest for the `Activity`

Also the item view should be of different view type, else you will see the entered text in other list items of `EditText` when you scroll. This happens due to recycle of view.

You can fix this by returning `getViewTypeCount` as list count

```
 public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return getCount();
    }
```

And change the `getItemViewType` to return a unique id , e.g., position is unique number

```
 public int getItemViewType(int position) {
     return position;
 }
```

Comment: This helped alot but one checkbox is coming in between..Actually I have total of 20 rows..getViewTypeCount() should be 2 for this ? and how do i get values/text of these checkbox/edittext

Comment: getViewTypeCount is the count of different types of view. In your case its 2

Comment: Thanks ! but problem is that one checkbox is coming in between checkbox and which gets changed if i scrolldown and scrollup the view .how do i make it constant

Comment: Issue could be some logic issue in get view. Review your code once again.

Comment: can you please check code above .. i am not getting error .. the code emulator behave so unexpectedly when i write anything in scroll downed EditText.

Comment: What was the issue . Are you able to input in `EditText` . If set android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" in manifest for the Activity

Comment: Yes This solved the error...displaying correctly.. but it gets crash onItemClick to get the Edittext text from rows 11 ..before that this works fine.. gives the nullpointer exception

Answer (score 0):

You have to explicitly define the `visibility` of your elements inside an `adapter`. Change your `adapter` code as below:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {



    View vi=convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;

    if(convertView==null){ 

        /********** Inflate tabitem.xml file for each row ( Defined below ) ************/
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tabitem, null); 

        /******** View Holder Object to contain tabitem.xml file elements ************/
        holder=new ViewHolder();
        holder.text=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        holder.check =(CheckBox)vi.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
         holder.text2=(EditText)vi.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
          holder.text2.setTag(1);
       int position12 = (Integer)holder.text2.getTag();
       System.out.print(position12 + "value");

       /************  Set holder with LayoutInflater ************/
        vi.setTag(holder);


        j++;

        if(j<8){
             holder.text2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
             holder.check.setX(-150);
             holder.check.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else
        {
             holder.check.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
             holder.text2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }



    }
    else  
        holder=(ViewHolder)vi.getTag();

    holder.text2.getText();
       if(data.size()<=0)
    {
        holder.text.setText("No Data");

        holder.text2.getText();
 //        Log.v("BBBB",  holder.text2.getText().toString());

    }
    else
    {
        /***** Get each Model object from Arraylist ********/
        tempValues=null;
        tempValues = (ListModel) data.get(position);

        /************  Set Model values in Holder elements ***********/
         holder.text.setText(tempValues.getCompanyName());

         holder.text2.getText();
                         /******** Set Item Click Listner for LayoutInflater for each row ***********/
         vi.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(position));
    }

    Log.v("DDD",  holder.text2.getText().toString());
    return vi;
}
```

This might help you.